# storing a 3kb json in cookies, as a file on server or in the database

Tags: php, mysql, json, cookies

I have a json file that I need to store for each user.

1. Storing as a cookie

   The json is 3kb so it's less than the 4kb limit the cookies have
2. Storing as a file on

   my server /json/user13.json
3. Storing in the database 

   (user_id (int, primary key), json (blob)

This will be retrieved quite often
The json file will be initially generated from the database and
I'm thinking of storing it as a cookie or file as a way to help
the server perform slightly faster.

Thank you!

Comment: This is why *sessions* exist in all modern Web frameworks. You shouldn't  store "data" in cookies - just a session key. Keep the data on the server side.

Comment: Meaning you favour the idea of saving it as a json file on the server side?

Comment: This is no sensitive data, it would not matter if someone viewed it.

Answer (score 1):

Will not let me put a simple comment so I extend a bit for fun, have you thought about using html5 localStorage?

Write:

```
var obj = {foo: 'bar'};
localStorage.setItem('obj', JSON.stringify(obj)); //<-- saved as JSON string
```

(saved as string because you can not save json objects in localStorage, soo, strings, and you has a 5 mb limit i think)

Read later:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('obj'));
```

I do not know if it's an option for you in this case

Edit:

For other browsers without localStorage can use https://github.com/wojodesign/local-storage-js

Basically when not have localStorage use or Global Storage:
 - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/storage#globalStorage

Or userData:
 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531424(v=vs.85).aspx

I do not know how much support 'back' is achieved, but allows browsers such as IE5, 6 and 7

Comment: I am aware of local storage but is it a reliable solution? I don't think many browsers support it. Meanwhile cookies is a more reliable solution as naturally all browsers support it.

Comment: Down voting because I want to slow the proliferation of web apps that store megabytes of crap ony machine. This what sessions are for, use them.

Comment: bornie for see browsers support you can see: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp
I only suggest ideas :)

Comment: Yes, IE 8+. My users are not the techy type with the latest available browsers, so that doesn't make a reliable solution in my case. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: https://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0
17% are "other" browsers I can't possibly know what they support, also there is the chance that even chrome/mozilla/ie users might have some outdated versions.

Comment: You has too this solution for IE6/7 and other browsers without localStorage https://github.com/wojodesign/local-storage-js

Comment: Does this use cookies? Is there still the 5MB limit? Thanks for your suggestion @Worvast

Comment: I add more explanation about this script in the answer in the top :). Np and good luck!